# Can Django Leak PII?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm writing a Tor hidden service in python 3, and debating whether to write my own web server with sockets or use a more powerful framework such as django. So my question is, should I be worried about django leaking personally identifiable information? And if it does, should I invest extra time into brewing my own web server or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: That hardly depends on how you use it. Anyway your question is too broad for SO. And it does not really involve programming code.

Comment: Django isn't really a web server.  It includes a development web server, but that shouldn't be used in production.  A common setup is to use gunicorn as the WSGI-compliant web server, and nginx as reverse proxy to serve static assets directly, and forward all other requests to gunicorn.